# How to execute multiple codes in a when block when their conditions is true?

Tags: kotlin

I'm aware that `when { }` can be used as a replacement to if-else branches. However, is it possible to execute multiple branches if the conditions are true?

Example:

```kotlin
val x = 5
val y = 4
    
when {
    x.isOdd() -> print("x is odd") //True, prints "x is odd"
    y.isEven() -> print("y is even") //Also True, but doesn't get executed
    else -> print("x+y is even.")
}
```

Is there any way so the second line is also executed?

Comment: No, `when`-expressions do not support fallthrough.

Comment: `when` is a chain of `if-elseif-elseif-...-else`

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this with a `when` statement, as `when` statements execute only the first block with a true condition.

The best way to do this when there are many different conditions, any number of which may be true and should be executed, and then a block you want to execute if *none* of them are true, is to use `if` statements and keep a `Boolean` variable (`handled` in the example below) to keep track of whether any have been executed, like so:

```kotlin
fun Int.isOdd() = this % 2 != 0
fun Int.isEven() = this % 2 == 0

val x = 5
val y = 4

var handled = false
if (x.isOdd()) {
    println("x is odd")
    handled = true
}
if (y.isEven()) {
    println("y is even")
    handled = true
}
// Add however many other conditions here

if (!handled) {
    // This will be executed if none of the above conditions are satisfied
    print("x is not odd and y is not even.")
}
```

([live demo](https://pl.kotl.in/lmO3dUMOE))

This prints:

```
x is odd
y is even
```

Answer (score -1):

Why you don't make the both printers in the same body if you want show the both.

Like:

```
when {
        x.isOdd()  && y.isEven() -> {print("x is odd\n y is even") }
        else -> print("x+y is even.")
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

As you said in the question, when is substitute of if-else. If you use if-else in your example, just first item will be printed. First condition is true so second one will not be checked. You can use something like this:

```
val x = 5
val y = 4   
         
        
if x.isOdd()
    print("x is odd")

if   y.isEven() 
    print("y is even")

if ((!x.isOdd())&&(y.isEven())||(x.isOdd())&&(!y.isEven())) 
    print("x+y is even.")
```

Comment: This answer has the right idea, but it would be a lot clearer if the indentation were fixed — and it won't compile without parens round the first two `if` conditions.  And that last `if` condition would be easier to read without the unnecessary parens and inversions: `if (x.isEven() && y.isEven() || x.isOdd() && y.isOdd())` — or better still `if ((x + y).isEven())`!

Comment: I think we can't say if ((x + y).isEven()) because in the question x and y are checked separately @gidds

Comment: I was thinking more of if there are 100 conditions, it would be a hassle to use if statements. But I guess there are no expressions available for that now.

Comment: It depends to that 100 conditions. You may handle them with when expression @RaymondSalim